# CSS - Changing between landscape and portrait positions

Tags: css, mobile, orientation, landscape, portrait

I try to adapt my website to smartphones. I used media types to do it:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px) and (orientation:landscape) { 
    /* Style here */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px) and (orientation:portrait) { 
    /* Style here */
}
```

Testing: I charge the webpage and it looks perfectly (portrait mode for example), change the orientation of the smartphone and the webpage adapt to landscape mode perfecly, **but comeback to portrait mode and the website turns to the "PC mode" (Don't using landscape-mode)**.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have tried `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`? [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) has an excellent guide to understand css mobile landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I used another media type:

> @media (orientation:portrait){
>
> }

(for example for portrait mode)

and now it works every time I change the orientation.